# How can I kill a process when I close the bash terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, process, kill-process

I have found many ways to keep a process running in the background after a bash terminal is closed. However, how can I do the opposite? How can I kill a background process when my terminal is closed?

Currently, when I close the terminal, I get "Processes are running in session... Close anyway?" and if I hit OK, the terminal closes, but the processes are not killed and linger around. Can I hook the suppression of these processes with the "death" of the terminal process?

Easy example: run `ssh-agent bash` and then try to close the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your `.bashrc`:

```
trap 'kill $(ps -o pid= --ppid $$) 2>/dev/null' exit
```

This command will make the shell kill all its child processes when you exit.

---

## Explanation:

---

The `trap` command catches signals and other events and lets you execute commands, that run when the signal is catched or the event has happened.

```
trap [-lp] [[arg] signal_spec ...]
```

ARG is a command to be read and executed when the shell receives the signal(s) SIGNAL_SPEC. If a SIGNAL_SPEC is EXIT, ARG is executed on exit from the shell.

---

The `kill` command sends a signal to the job(s) of PID(s) supplied as arguments.

```
kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid ...
```

If neither SIGSPEC nor SIGNUM is present, then SIGTERM (termination signal) is assumed.

---

The `ps` command displays information about processes.

```
-o format
    User defined format of output.
--ppid pidlist
    Select which processes to show by PID of their parent process. Selects processes
    that are children of those listed in PIDLIST.
```

---

Finally, `$$` in shell expands to the process id of the shell. In a `$(...)` subshell, it expands to the process ID of the current shell, not the subshell.

And `2>/dev/null` is used to discard potential error output of the kill command which can be caused by processes that no longer exist when the kill command is executed, but existed while the ps command was executed - which is typically the subshell `$(...)`.

Comment: This didn't work for me. While testing with `ssh-agent bash`, I tried adding this line to `.bashrc`, then tried adding it to `.profile`, but when I close the terminal the ssh-agent is still running. Should this line work if I run `ssh-agent bash` from `.profile` or does this change anything?

Comment: Looks like `ssh-agent` sometimes needs a few seconds to stop its activities. When I open new terminal, type `ssh-agent bash` and close the terminal window, then do `pgrep -a ssh-agent`, until I can see that the ssh-agent command closes after a few seconds. However, in this case you don't even need the trap, because this ssh-agent command runs in foreground and exits when you close the terminal.

Comment: To try the trap command on a background process, you can try `ssh-agent sleep 1000 &`, then close terminal. The process gets killed afterwards, again taking a few seconds.

Comment: Eventually managed to make it work with some fiddling and `ssh-agent -k`